# OAuth2 Facebook - not running

Tags: java, angular, typescript, oauth-2.0

Edit: Working with Angular2 -

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 to make users log in using Facebook/Github.
When I'm at localhost:4200/login I simply click "log in with facebook" and it tries to redirect to localhost:4200/login/facebook BUT then it gives me the error:

```html
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login/facebook'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login/facebook'
```

What could be wrong? I've spent hours trying to figure it out but with no luck.  Am I missing anything?

In my OAuth2Index.ts file I have the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'OAuth2Index',
  templateUrl: './auth-server/src/main/resources/static/index.html',
  // styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class OAuth2IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

It displays the index.html file, which has:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <title>Demo</title>
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <base href="/" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></scr>
 <script type="text/javascript"
     src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="home as home">
     <h1>Login</h1>
     <div class="container" ng-show="!home.authenticated">
         <div>
             With Facebook: <a href="/login/facebook">click here</a>
         </div>
         <div>
             With Github: <a href="/login/github">click here</a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container" ng-show="home.authenticated">
         Logged in as: <span ng-bind="home.user"></span>
         <div>
             <button ng-click="home.logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
         </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular
            .module("app", [])
            .config(
                    function($httpProvider) {
                        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
                    }).controller("home", function($http, $location) {
                var self = this;
                $http.get("/user").success(function(data) {
                    if (data.name) {
                        self.user = data.name;
                        self.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        self.user = "N/A";
                        self.authenticated = false;
                    }
                }).error(function() {
                    self.user = "N/A";
                    self.authenticated = false;
                });
                self.logout = function() {
                    $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
                        self.authenticated = false;
                        $location.path("/");
                    }).error(function(data) {
                        console.log("Logout failed")
                        self.authenticated = false;
                    });
                };
            });
</script>
```

Please notice the: "With Facebook: [click here](/login/facebook)
xxxx"

I have some beans in my SocialApplication.java file that should handle the action when user clicks login with facebook (i.e. /login/facebook).

```js
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2015 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.example;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

 @RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
 public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
  Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  map.put("name", principal.getName());
  return map;
 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  // @formatter:off
  http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
    .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and().logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
    .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  // @formatter:on
 }

 @Configuration
 @EnableResourceServer
 protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   // @formatter:off
   http.antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
   // @formatter:on
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
 }

 @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
  FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
  registration.setFilter(filter);
  registration.setOrder(-100);
  return registration;
 }

 @Bean
 @ConfigurationProperties("github")
 public ClientResources github() {
  return new ClientResources();
 }

 @Bean
 @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
 public ClientResources facebook() {
  return new ClientResources();
 }

 private Filter ssoFilter() {
  CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
  List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
  filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
  filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
  filter.setFilters(filters);
  return filter;
 }

 private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
  OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
    path);
  OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
  filter.setRestTemplate(template);
  UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
    client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId());
  tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
  filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
  return filter;
 }

}

class ClientResources {

 @NestedConfigurationProperty
 private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

 @NestedConfigurationProperty
 private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

 public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
  return client;
 }

 public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
  return resource;
 }
}
```

I'm my app-routing.module.ts I have:

```
      const routes: Routes = [

   // {path: 'index.html ', data: {title: 'Login'}, component: LoginComponent},
   // {path: 'login', data: {title: 'Login'}, component: LoginComponent},

   // {path: 'index ', data: {title: 'Login'}, component: OAuthIndexComponent},
   {path: 'login', data: {title: 'Login'}, component: OAuth2IndexComponent},
   {path: 'signup', data: {title: 'Login'}, component:      UserRegistrationComponent},
   {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login'},
   {
     path:'',component: AppWrap,
     children:[
       {path: 'cars', data: {title: 'Car'}, component: ProductsComponent},
       {path: 'cars/:id', data: {title: 'Car'}, compoent:      ProductSingleDetailComponent},
       // {path: 'login/facebook', data: {title: 'facebookLogin'},      component: OAuth2IndexComponent}

     ]
   }
 ];
```

In my app.module.ts I have remembered to declare OAuth2IndexComponent.

Comment: is this `angular2` or `angular1` or what it is actually?

Comment: Angular2 - I just made it more clear in the post. Thanks :)

Comment: are you using `angularjs` inside angular2 ??

Comment: Yes I am, Aravind.

Comment: You will not be able to do it. Sorry. what is the reason for using that way??  **`Angular 1 can wrap Angular 2` but not vice versa**

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_click :/ 

So I really can't do it this way? I need to start all over?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143434/discussion-between-aravind-and-adem-okmen).